Deselecting duplicate records in QGIS Attribute table
Several SE-GIS posts describe how to identify duplicate records, such as Identifying duplicate attributes in field using QGIS.
I would like to extend this concept by unselecting any duplicate records that are in a selected set. For example, consider this simple table, where a selection has been made wherein three of the four selected records (shown bolded) have duplicate values:
FID VALUE
1    A
2    B
3    B
4    B
5    C
6    D
My goal is to unselect the duplicates, as follows:
FID VALUE
1    A
2    B
3    B
4    B
5    C
6    D
I've been manually unselecting the duplicate records, but would prefer some sort of expression that would do this unselecting. A review of the QGIS expressions turned up nothing.
Any of the duplicates can be unselected since those records are all equal. Thus, no first/last logic needs to be applied.

When using the select by expression you have several choice beside the default select feature, just choose "Remove from Current Selection" and use an expression that select duplicate except the first...

Using Select by Expression and the option Filter Current Selection.
The FID values are aggregated into arrays, grouped by the VALUE field. The current feature's FID is evaluated against the first FID from each group.
"FID" = array_first(
          array_agg(
              "FID",
              group_by:="VALUE"
          )
        )

Before:

After:


Well done, @Matt.  For my own future reference, replacing the expression array_first with array_last would return the duplicate with the last (largest) FID value, instead of the first (smallest) FID value.

I can suggest a PyQGIS solution.
Proceed with Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor (see documentation) and paste the script below:
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# getting a layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")[0]

# checking if selection on the layer exists
if layer.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:
    # a dict of selected features IDs with values taken from the "type" field
    selection = {feat.id(): feat["FIELD"] for feat in layer.selectedFeatures()}
    # a reverse dict
    rev_selection = {v: k for k, v in selection.items()}
    # a list with IDs for a new selection
    new_selection = list(rev_selection.values())
    # selecting new features
    layer.selectByIds(new_selection)

In the code above, please do not forget to change the "YOUR_LAYER_NAME" and feat["FIELD"] variables before running it.
Press Run script  and observe how the selection will be modified.
Input:

Output:


References:

Reverse / invert a dictionary mapping


You can use the "Delete Duplicates by Attribute" tool

Thanks, Dimitris, but I don't want to delete duplicates, I want to unselect them.
